# Grey pieces: 4x12 plate with cutouts, 2x4 hinge with only four studs on one side, 1x2 plate with big cylinder on the side

Tags: part-identification

Can someone tell me the part numbers of the following pieces? Unfortunately there aren't any numbers on the pieces. [image: 3 mystery pieces]

Answer (score 11):

The hinge is [3149c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3149c01). The engine is [3475](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=3475*) (or possibly other, similar molds).

Answer (score 11):

RSchulz has correctly identified two elements, so I'll address the last one which is [Vehicle, Base 4 x 12 for Steering Gear (803)](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=803). Light Gray colored version was available in [3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=803&colorID=9&in=A).

Comment: I gave up on searching for Plate, as I figured it was an old base for trains or the like. But I kept insisting on using slot or hole, when I should have just searched for base with 4x12. Gah.